# How to implement elasticsearch range filters in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, erb, tire

I have an index in elasticsearch named univ which has univ_name, state, rank and acceptance attributes. I was able to implement facet search on univ_name based on the state. I would like to implement facets such as displaying univ index values with rank ranging from 1-5. My current view file appears as

```
<ul>
<% @univ.facets['univ']['terms'].each do |facet| %>
<li class="nav-header">
<%= link_to_unless_current Univ.find(facet['term']).state, params.merge(id: facet['term'])   %> 
<%if params[:id] == facet['term'].to_s %>
(<%= link_to "remove", id: nil%>)
<%else%>
(<%= facet['count']%>)
<%end%>
</li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

How can ranges be implemented? is there a way that I could use a condition on

```
<%= link_to_unless_current Univ.find(facet['term']).rank, params.merge(id: facet['term'])   %>
```

to search based on range of rank values?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are asking for

Comment: @phoet I am a newbie in elasticsearch I tried to implement basic faceting and I want to how can I implement facets based on ranges such as product with price range between $10-50

Comment: I used this to implement ranges in my app http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ maybe would help you